# Character string formula (from paste()) does not work with randomForest()

Tags: r

I am trying to use randomForest with a formula that's been constructed through the paste() function. However, randomForest refuses to accept such a formula, while rpart does. Does anyone know how I can get this to work?

```
library(rpart)
library(randomForest)

# Construct a formula by pasting stuff together.
columnName <- "Species"
modelFormula <- paste(columnName, " ~ .")
print(modelFormula)
## [1] "Species  ~ ."


# Call rpart() and randomForest() with the constructed model.
model <- rpart(modelFormula, data=iris)
model <- randomForest(modelFormula, data=iris)
## Error in if (n == 0) stop("data (x) has 0 rows") : 
##   argument is of length zero

# This works if I directly include the formula.
model <- randomForest(Species ~ ., data=iris)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to coerce the character string to a formula object (using `as.formula()`) for it to work with `randomForest()`:

```
R> model <- randomForest(as.formula(modelFormula), data=iris)
R> model

Call:
 randomForest(formula = as.formula(modelFormula), data = iris) 
               Type of random forest: classification
                     Number of trees: 500
No. of variables tried at each split: 2

        OOB estimate of  error rate: 4.67%
Confusion matrix:
           setosa versicolor virginica class.error
setosa         50          0         0        0.00
versicolor      0         47         3        0.06
virginica       0          4        46        0.08
```

There is a bit of a difference between the character string and to formula object

```
R> modelFormula
[1] "Species  ~ ."
R> as.formula(modelFormula)
Species ~ .
```

This is important, as there is a `formula` method which kicks in if you supply a formula object as the first argument. If you don't, you get the `default` method and that doesn't know what to do with a character string for it's argument `x`. You can see the method dispatch at work below:

```
R> methods(randomForest)
[1] randomForest.default* randomForest.formula*

   Non-visible functions are asterisked
R> debugonce(randomForest:::randomForest.formula)
R> model <- randomForest(modelFormula, data=iris) ## 1
Error in if (n == 0) stop("data (x) has 0 rows") : 
  argument is of length zero
R> model <- randomForest(as.formula(modelFormula), data=iris)
debugging in: randomForest.formula(as.formula(modelFormula), data = iris)
debug: {
.... truncated
```

I debugged the `formula` method but it doesn't get called until you pass a formula object as the first argument. Hence the error in the first call (`## 1` above). With a formula object, we see that the `randomForest.formula` method was invoked as we drop into the debugger.

Comment: Thanks. Why don't I need as.formula() for rpart()?

Comment: @stackoverflowuser2010 The opposite reason of why `randomForest` doesn't work. Look at `methods(rpart)` and you'll notice that there are no methods for this function (`rpart()` isn't *even* an S3 generic function). If you look at `?rpart` you'll see the first argument for the function is a formula and the code that it runs can handle a formula in character string format. So `rpart` expects a formula, `randomForest.default` doesn't, and method dispatch is catching you out.

Comment: @stackoverflowuser2010 I suspect, but haven't tried, that `randomForest:::randomForest.formula(modelFormula, data iris)` could well work too as the code it runs is similar to that which `rpart` runs, to build the model frame and then the model matrix from the symbolic formula.

Answer (score 1):

Do:

```
model <- randomForest(as.formula(modelFormula), data=iris)
```

Result:

```
> model

Call:
 randomForest(formula = as.formula(modelFormula), data = iris) 
               Type of random forest: classification
                     Number of trees: 500
No. of variables tried at each split: 2

        OOB estimate of  error rate: 4%
Confusion matrix:
           setosa versicolor virginica class.error
setosa         50          0         0        0.00
versicolor      0         47         3        0.06
virginica       0          3        47        0.06
```